# Exit loop in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I have a simple AHK script as follows:

```
Loop, 10
{  
    Click 745,664
    SetMouseDelay, 100
    Click 345,635
    SetMouseDelay, 25
    Click 878,471
    SetMouseDelay, 25
    Click 772,557
    SetMouseDelay, 25
    Click 552,387
    SetMouseDelay, 25
    Click 578,516
    SetMouseDelay, 150
}
```

What I want to be able to do is just add in some way of being able to stop the loop such as pressing certain keys but any example that I have tried hasn't been successful for me.

It is probably very simple but I have only just started using AHK and I am still getting used to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exit the loop using [GetKeyState()](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#GetKeyState) and [break](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Break.htm) like so:

```
Loop, 10
{  
    Click 745,664
    SetMouseDelay, 100
    Click 345,635
    SetMouseDelay, 25
    Click 878,471
    SetMouseDelay, 25
    Click 772,557
    SetMouseDelay, 25
    Click 552,387
    SetMouseDelay, 25
    Click 578,516
    SetMouseDelay, 150
    if GetKeyState("Shift", "P") ; Looks to see if Shift is pressed
        break  ; exits Loop
}
```